# dtype object cannot be converted to float matplotlib

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I have been trying to run the following code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv2.imread("G:\myfiles\frames\frame1.jpg",0)
image = [img]
for i in range(1):
    plt.subplot(1, 1, i+1), plt.imshow(image[i], 'gray')
    plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-b2519be4ee9a> in <module>
      1 image = [img]
      2 for i in range(1):
----> 3     plt.subplot(1, 1, i+1), plt.imshow(image[i], 'gray')
      4     plt.xticks([]),plt.yticks([])
      5 

E:\anaconda\programme files\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in imshow(X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, data, **kwargs)
   2728         filternorm=filternorm, filterrad=filterrad, resample=resample,
   2729         url=url, **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}),
-> 2730         **kwargs)
   2731     sci(__ret)
   2732     return __ret

E:\anaconda\programme files\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in inner(ax, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1445     def inner(ax, *args, data=None, **kwargs):
   1446         if data is None:
-> 1447             return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
   1448 
   1449         bound = new_sig.bind(ax, *args, **kwargs)

E:\anaconda\programme files\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py in imshow(self, X, cmap, norm, aspect, interpolation, alpha, vmin, vmax, origin, extent, filternorm, filterrad, resample, url, **kwargs)
   5521                               resample=resample, **kwargs)
   5522 
-> 5523         im.set_data(X)
   5524         im.set_alpha(alpha)
   5525         if im.get_clip_path() is None:

E:\anaconda\programme files\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py in set_data(self, A)
    701                 not np.can_cast(self._A.dtype, float, "same_kind")):
    702             raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
--> 703                             "float".format(self._A.dtype))
    704 
    705         if self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] == 1:

TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

This is the specific error, seems like matplotlib causes the error

```
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

Why this error arises what is the possible fix for this?

Comment: This kind of question has been asked several times but all of them have zero responses,  it would be helpful if someone provides a solution

Comment: Unescaped backslashes in the file path, and no test whether `imread` succeeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to escape the backslashes in your path, as backslashes are special characters used to escape special characters.

You can try:

```
img = cv2.imread("G:\\myfiles\\frames\\frame1.jpg", 0)
```

Or you can use an `r`-string:

```
img = cv2.imread(r"G:\myfiles\frames\frame1.jpg", 0)
```

Lastly, you can try using forward slashes instead of backslashes:

```
img = cv2.imread("G:/myfiles/frames/frame1.jpg", 0)
```